# Angularjs promised using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
    url: '/checkUsername',
    data:{name:$scope.username},
    method: "POST"
})
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.gameStart = true;
})
```

For some reason $scope.gameStart cannot be within then(), it has to be outside. How do I use $scope.gameStart after my ajax call finished, without putting my code within it?

Comment: Why do you think it cannot be within the `then()` call?

Comment: Can you please post more code, in order to find out what's going on? This is a very small portion of your code.
Please provide more info as well on your question

Comment: @str assume it work but I want to put a function instead of bunch of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some function instead bunch of code

```
$http({
    url: '/checkUsername',
    data:{name:$scope.username},
    method: "POST"
})
.then(bunchOfCode)

function bunchOfCode(response) {
    console.log('response', response); // still have access to it
    $scope.gameStart = true;
}
```

Comment: what if the call has callback param like the response?

Comment: Declare function with one argument (it will be filled by response) - then JavaScript magic will happen - you have still access to `response`

Answer (score -1):

if You want the value of this "$scope.gamestart" outside of then, For this you may use the $.q , for Example..

```
 var defer = $q.defer();
 $http.get('options.json').success(function(result{                  
 defer.resolve(result);
 });
 var value = defer.promise;
```

Comment: I guess because `$http` already returns a promise based on `$q`.